# change content-type HTTP header google drive file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to proxy a file  and use that header with php: `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");`

My code:

```
<?php
$id = '0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc';

$ch = curl_init('https://drive.google.com/uc?id='.$id.'&export=download'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, []);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$object = json_decode(str_replace(')]}\'', '', $result));

exit(header('Location: '. $object->downloadUrl));
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;)
```

What should i do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply add a header redirect, along with the additional headers. When the browser sees the location header, it will move to the new location and read those headers from the response. You'll need to output the file directly from google drive (Which requires the server to download the file, and relay it to the client. Something like so):

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');
$ch2 = curl_init($object->downloadUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, []);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_exec($ch2);
```

Comment: will the files be saved on my own server?

Comment: No, they'll be immediately output, but they will be using **your server resources** to both download the file, and relay it to the end client.